# How to open an app from a link in an email on Android?

Tags: android, ios, android-intent, uri, intentfilter

If I call "myapp://" from Safari, it open correctly my app.

I used the URL Scheme and it works perfectly, here is the tutorial I followed : [URL Scheme](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Now I would like to open my app from an email. On Gmail for example, you can only send an hyperlink if this one can't handle http/https/www. If I send an hyperlink with "myapp://", the hyperlink is automatically suppressed.

I cannot call a dummy web page that would redirect to "myapp://" because any webpage on my server needs an authentication.

I just wanted to know if there is no other possibilities yet to open a Mobile Application from an email without having to call a webpage first ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the `scheme` & `host` of the `Uri` to the `intent-filter` of your app's launch `Activity` in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.somedomain.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="myappuri.com"
            android:scheme="https" />

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Now when you supply a `Uri` in the email as `https://myappuri.com`, it will implicitly open your app (or rather open a list of apps to choose from that includes your app).

**References:**

**1.** [**Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html).

**2.** [`<data>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html).

Comment: I didn't tested on Android yet, is there a chance that you have the same possibilities on iOS :) ?

Comment: Doubtful. `iOS` doesn't have any equivalent of the concept of `Intent`.

Comment: Perfect, I will use that for Android anyway, too bad iOS doesn't have an equivalent...